# What Wait() Actually means in Java ? I will Wait or You Wait?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

As my  understanding, if I am thread then:

- When I call  `notify()`/`notifyAll()` it means means I am sending a signal to other thread which
  are waiting on this object monitor. Am I right?
- But What the `wait()` means?

  **Am I sending signal to other thread to wait so that I can complete my work on it?**
  Or
  **I am declaring that I will wait, You do your work and tell me when you are done.?**

*I have a little concept about threads*

Comment: You are waiting for some to notify you of something...

Comment: Take some time to read through [Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and don't be afriad to try some test...

Comment: The latter. But this can be read in any documentation about this topic, including the [API doc about `wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) itself.

Comment: the thread in which you declare wait() will wait. It will resume its execution when you notify him.

Comment: i think it a good question - because this is an very very old method and the expression `wait` is not so clear!! `Thread.waitForNotificaion()` would be surely a better method name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means *you* want to wait for a notification.

As per the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) (my emphasis):

> Causes the *current* thread to wait until *another* thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for *this* object.

Comment: Then I have a little confusion. Suppose some one call notify on an object and I am not waiting on that specific object monitor but i am working with that object. Is it a valid situation?if yes then will it affect by behavior?

Comment: if you want i can update my question with this part.

Comment: Both threads need to use the same monitor object for this to work. If someone calls `notify` on an unrelated object, you will continue to wait.

Comment: i got this part thanks. But i am just wondering as all other newbie  if i am not waiting some object but using it as a property or some thing and some other thread called notify on that object? is that type of situation can happen or its not possible logically? if yes then will it affect me .@Thilo

Comment: @Saif, you need to look at the notify docs - they state "If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened." Hence, if no threads are waiting, none can be woken up. That's why waiters should check their condition before trying to wait, in case a notify was given with no-one waiting.

Comment: @Saif, `o.notify()` does not do anything at all if there are no other threads waiting in an `o.wait()` call.  The object, o, does not remember that it was notified if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to be clear of. Thanks @jameslarge

Answer (score 1):

It means **"I am declaring that I will wait, You do your work and tell me when you are done."**

Document Says,

Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object. In other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call wait(0).
The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

[See this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())

Comment: `wait()` does not _declare_ anything.  It just waits.